# Minimizing a function containing an integral

Tags: math, matlab, simulation, mathematical-optimization, numerical-integration

Does anyone know how to minimize a function containing an integral in MATLAB? The function looks like this:

```
L = Int(t=0,t=T)[(AR-x)dt], A is a system parameter and R and x are related through:  
dR/dt = axRY - bR, where a and b are constants.  
dY/dt = -xRY
```

I read somewhere that I can use fminbnd and quad in combination but I am not able to make it work. Any suggestions?

Comment: great question.  have you found a solution?  if not, would you be interested in making this question more general -- i.e., about minimizing *any* function containing an integral, rather than your particular function?  i'd be willing to start a bounty for such a general question.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could give more details of your integral, e.g. where is the missing bracket in `[AR-x)dt]`? Is there any dependence of `x` on `t`, or can we integrate `dR/dt = axR - bR` to give `R=C*exp((a*x-b)*t)`? In any case, to answer your question on `fminbnd` and `quad`, you could set `A,C,T,a,b,xmin` and `xmax` (the last two are the range you want to look for the min over) and use:

```
 [x fval] = fminbnd(@(x) quad(@(t)A*C*exp((a*x-b)*t)-x,0,T),xmin,xmax)
```

This finds `x` that minimizes the integral.

Comment: Ah... I thought I added a second equation as well. I apologize for that... Will add the second one in a second. Thanks for the pointers, I will currently look into that. However, I am curious how your answer might change for my revised question...

Answer (score 0):

If i didn't get it wrong you are trying to minimize respect to t:

```
\int_0^t{(AR-x) dt}
```

well then you just need to find the zeros of:

```
AR-x
```

This is just math, not matlab ;)

Comment: Thanks... Would you mind fixing the latex in your post? I don't seem to be able to see it for some reason...

Comment: unfortunately texify doesn't support external linking. Past the code here http://www.texify.com/links.php to see the image.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some manipulation of your equations that might help.

Combining the second and third equations you gave gives

```
dR/dt = -a*(dY/dt)-bR
```

Now if we solve for R on the righthand side and plug it into the first equation you gave we get

```
L = Int(t=0,t=T)[(-A/b*(dR/dt + a*dY/dt) - x)dt]
```

Now we can integrate the first term to get:

```
L = -A/b*[R(T) - R(0) + Y(T) - Y(0)] - Int(t=0,t=T)[(x)dt]
```

So now all that matters with regards to R and Y are the endpoints. In fact, you may as well define a new function, Z which equals Y + R. Then you get

```
L = -A/b*[Z(T) - Z(0)] - Int(t=0,t=T)[(x)dt]
```

This next part I'm not as confident in.  The integral of x with respect to t will give some function which is evaluated at t = 0 and t = T.  This function we will call X to give:

```
L = -A/b*[Z(T) - Z(0)] - X(T) + X(0)
```

This equation holds true for all T, so we can set T to t if we want to.

```
L = -A/b*[Z(t) - Z(0)] - X(t) + X(0)
```

Also, we can group a lot of the constants together and call them C to give

```
X(t) = -A/b*Z(t) + C
```

where

```
C = A/b*Z(0) + X(0) - L
```

So I'm not sure what else to do with this, but I've shown that the integral of x(t) is linearly related to Z(t) = R(t) + Y(t).  It seems to me that there are many equations that solve this. Anyone else see where to go from here? Any problems with my math?